# Guava Ratelimiter tryAcquire returns true only for the first call(any number of permits)?

Tags: java, guava

I am using Guava 18.0 RateLimiter:

```
public static void simpleTst() throws Exception{
    RateLimiter lt = RateLimiter.create(2);
    _log.info("Acquired one " + lt.tryAcquire());
    _log.info("Acquired two " + lt.tryAcquire());
}
```

The output is:

```
: 08 16:22:10 PST.INFO1*RateLimiterTst~simpleTst@37: Acquired one true
: 08 16:22:10 PST.INFO1*RateLimiterTst~simpleTst@38: Acquired two false
```

Specifying the number of permits to `12`:

```
public static void simpleTst() throws Exception{
    RateLimiter lt = RateLimiter.create(2);
    _log.info("Acquired one " + lt.tryAcquire(12));
    _log.info("Acquired two " + lt.tryAcquire());
}
```

The output is:

```
: 08 16:22:36 PST.INFO1*RateLimiterTst~simpleTst@37: Acquired one true
: 08 16:22:36 PST.INFO1*RateLimiterTst~simpleTst@38: Acquired two false
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 9):

The behaviour of the first example is expected because:

```
// we request 2 permit per seconds
RateLimiter lt = RateLimiter.create(2);
_log.info("Acquired one " + lt.tryAcquire());

// waiting 1/2 second we will be able to get the second permit
Thread.sleep(500);
_log.info("Acquired two " + lt.tryAcquire());
```

The output is:

```
Acquired one true
Acquired two true
```

From the Guava docs:

> The returned RateLimiter ensures that on average no more than
>   permitsPerSecond are issued during any given second, with sustained
>   requests being **smoothly spread over each second**.

The behaviour of the second example is expected too because to successfully get the single permit on the second "Acquire" we need to wait around 6 seconds (= 12 / 2)

```
// we request 2 permit per seconds
RateLimiter lt = RateLimiter.create(2);

// trying to acquire 12 permits
_log.info("Acquired one " + lt.tryAcquire(12));

// waiting 12 / 2 seconds in order to be able to get the second permit
Thread.sleep(6000);
_log.info("Acquired two " + lt.tryAcquire());
```

The output is:

```
Acquired one true
Acquired two true
```

Trying to acquire the last permit waiting less than 6 seconds would fail, that is why `lt.tryAcquire()` in your example returns `false`.

Comment: Thanks. In the second case, how come the first tryAcquire(12) returns true as permitsPerSecond is 2. Can you please clarify that ?

Comment: `if an expensive task arrives at an idle RateLimiter, it will be granted immediately, but it is the next request that will experience extra throttling, thus paying for the cost of the expensive task` source guava javadoc http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html

Answer (score 0):

If you will sleep an app for 1ms, it will return true and true.